# What is the relationship between gaussian mixture models and covariate regression?

Tags: finite-mixture-model

Consider a histogram of observations $y$ which look a bit like this,

[image]

Imagine that the two bell-curve shaped histograms (ignore the actual fitted curves) correspond to observations from females and males respectively. One way to model this could be

```
lm(y ~ gender)
```

Now, I found this particular picture in a text on Gaussian mixture models. I understand that if we did not have the explanatory variable 'gender', then we might model this as a Gaussian mixture model.... but since we do, then we could decide to just use a single model with gender as a covariate, like the lm above.

What is the relationship between these two approaches? What would've happened if I had used a mixture model here? Can they be shown to give identical conclusions?

Answer (score 1):

In the linear model, the assumption of the distribution of ERROR term, instead of response variable itself, is needed. So we cannot select the model based on the distribution of Y. We should fit the model first, get the residuals (estimate of the error term), and check the distribution (histogram) of the residuals. If the histogram of the residual displays multiple modals (un-normality), we may consider the mixture model.
In summary, mixture model is used when the un-normality exists in error terms (displayed by histogram of the residuals).